# Reading multiple PDF files in order

Tags: java, multithreading, pdf, import, pdfbox

I split PDF files into multiple pdf files and then I am trying to read multiple pdf files from the folder and print out file names.

```
int l=1;
File file = new File(userInputFile);
try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file)) {

    Splitter splitter = new Splitter();
    List<PDDocument> Pages = splitter.split(document);
    Iterator<PDDocument> iterator = Pages.listIterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        PDDocument pd = iterator.next();    
        pd.save("C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\FolderForCheckListTest_000\\"+"Page "+l++);
    }

    document.close();
}
```

Files in folder:
Page 1, Page 2. Page 3, Page 4, Page 5, Page 6, Page 7, Page 8, Page 9 and Page 10.

When I read these files and print them I get incorrect order:
Page 1, Page 10, Page 2 and so on.

Here is my code for reading files:

```
 for (File ListOfFile : ListOfFiles) {
    if (ListOfFile.isFile()) {
        files  = ListOfFile.getName();
        if (files.startsWith("Page")){
            000\\multiplePDFtest\\";
            String nfiles = path;
            PDFManager pdfManager = new PDFManager();
            String pdfToText = pdfManager.pdftoText(nfiles+files);
            listStrings.add(pdfToText);
        }
    }
}
```

Do you know how to fix it?
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create fixed filename lengths, change this

```
pd.save("C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\FolderForCheckListTest_000\\"+"Page "+l++);
```

to this

```
pd.save("C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\FolderForCheckListTest_000\\"+"Page "+String.format("%02d",l++));
```

(for clarity, I recommend to put the "++" outside, but that's another story)

Answer (score 1):

Default sorting is being done on String hence 10 will come after 1 and followed by 2 etc..

Implement a custom sort ([Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)) and use on the list of file names collection ([Collections.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator))) and handle the sorting appropriately, ie, treat the end digits as number.

Comment: or name the files "01", "02" by using `String.format("%02d",l)` instead of `l`

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr do you mean something like this? ```pd.save("C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\FolderForCheckListTest_000\\"+String.format("%02d", l));```?